# R help conflict with multiple packages

Tags: r

I'm working in R 3.1.1 on OS X from the terminal. When I ask for help and there is a conflict, I get this message and R just hangs for a minute or two:

```
> ?xlim
Help on topic ‘xlim’ was found in the following packages:

  Package               Library
  ggplot2               /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library
  graphics              /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library
```

Eventually R responds to my `CTRL+C` interrupt and gives the R shell back. Is there anything I can do to prevent R from hanging?

Comment: I don't have a mac anymore but when that happens does another window popup (possibly hidden behind other stuff) that allows you to choose which help page you want to view?

Comment: Thanks Dason, in the past I do remember an X11 window popping up asking but it's not popping up now. I'll keep a lookout for it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to specify name space before calling the help manual.

```
>library(dplyr)
>library(plyr)
...

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise, summarize

> ?dplyr::arrange
> ?plyr::arrange
```

Also, `?'?'` will give you some interesting information about how `?` works, it is basically a shortcut for command `help`. By looking up `help` command, you can also pass certain arguments to clear the confusion when looking up functions that might exist in more than one loaded libraries.

```
help(arrange, package=dplyr)
```

Comment: That's useful, but in this case I didn't expect xlim to be masked so I didn't know I needed to specify a package in advance of calling help.